# How to add custom machine images when creating Kubernetes cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-cluster

When the vm instances are created on cluster creation I'm not able to change project wide ssh with out removing the vm instance from the vm instance group.Is there any way to do this

Comment: Do you want to update the existing machine type in your initial node pool?

Comment: can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Im trying to edit an existing cluster where i need to set ipForwarding off and change access scopes on the vm instances which were created by kubenetes.

Comment: Could you please explain in more details what you are trying to achieve? What means "custom machine images"?